# How to set the Gridview row background color in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have gridview with 21 rows. My requirement is to set some of rows background color is Light Green(like 1,5,13 rows) is this possible to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [How to dynamically assign a BackColor to a GridView row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305268/how-to-dynamically-assign-a-backcolor-to-a-gridview-row)

Comment: Have you finally made your choice? Not that I mind much, but having your own answer unaccepted, then accepted over 5 times in 10 months tends to get pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through each gridview row and assign the row's back colour:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in yourGridView.Rows) {
      row.BackColor = Color.Green; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
viewerDataGrid.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = myColor;
```